# xamarin ios change language via view not via settings of the phone

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm working with localization. So the structure ( Base.lproj folders, Localizable.strings ) is already setup and the app is loaded in the correct language (depending on your phone settings). However, in the app, the user needs to be able to change the language via a view. How can I change the language on the fly without restarting the app.
here a solution but it seems not very good

```
    var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("fr", "lproj");
    var languageBundle = NSBundle.FromPath(path);
    var myLocalizedString = languageBundle.LocalizedString("locloc", " ");
```

Comment: https://www.factorialcomplexity.com/blog/2015/01/28/how-to-change-localization-internally-in-your-ios-application.html

Comment: i don't know how to translate it to xamarin as i'm new to xamarin and c# very beginner.@SushiHangover.
also i find a solution but not very good :
 view my update question